# Limit posted fields for insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to limit the fields a user can post when inserting an object in mongodb. I know ho i can enforce fields to be filled but I can't seem to find how to people from inserting fields that I don't want.

This is the code I have now for inserting an item.

```
app.post("/obj", function (req, res) {
    var newObj = req.body;

    //TODO filter fields I don't want ?

    if (!(newObj .id || newObj .type)) {
        handleError(res, "Invalid input", "Must provide a id and type.",    400);
        return;
    }

    db.collection(OBJ_COLLECTION).insertOne(newObj, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new object.");
        } else {
            res.status(201).json(doc.ops[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely JS native ways to do this, but I tend to use [Lodash](http://lodash.com) as my toolbox for most projects, and in that case what I normally do is setup a whitelist of allowed fields, and then extract only those from the posted values like so:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

app.post("/obj", function (req, res) {
    var newObj = _.pick(req.body, ['id', 'type','allowedField1','allowedField2']);
```

This is pretty straightforward, and I usually also define the whitelist somewhere else for reuse (e.g. on the model or the like).

As a side note, I avoid using 'id' as a field that someone can post to for new objects, unless I really need to, to avoid confusion with the autogenerated _id field.

Also, you should really look into [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) rather than using the straight mongodb driver, if you want to have more model-based control of your documents.  Among other things, it will strip any fields off the object if they're not defined in the schema.  I still use the `_.pick()` method when there are things that *are* defined in the schema, but I don't want people to change in a particular controller method.